# Facebook wall posts in my chrome extension

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How can I get Facebook wall posts into my chrome extension?

I don't see any API that does this. Can I get HTML of the facebook page via XMLHttpRequest and parse it ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should be able to get it using :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: For this to work, I first need to create an app on Facebook. Right? Because to get ACCESS_TOKEN it's asking me to provide YOUR_APP_ID.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It's the easiest way, I think. Getting the html and parsing it will be a headache. You´ve probably seen it already, but just in case: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/